# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "flutter_google_places_sdk_ios"

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, google-places-api

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "flutter_google_places_sdk_ios":
In Podfile:
flutter_google_places_sdk_ios (from .symlinks/plugins/flutter_google_places_sdk_ios/ios)

Specs satisfying the flutter_google_places_sdk_ios (from .symlinks/plugins/flutter_google_places_sdk_ios/ios) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this by following:

Navigated to

> Podfile

`platform :ios, '12.1'`

to

`platform :ios, '13.0'`

Answer (score -1):

The error message indicates that there's a compatibility issue with the deployment target for the `flutter_google_places_sdk_ios` dependency in your Flutter project.

To resolve this, you can try the following steps:

1. **Update Deployment Target**:

   Open the `Podfile` located in the `ios` directory of your Flutter project. Look for the line that specifies the deployment target for `flutter_google_places_sdk_ios`:

   ```rb
   platform :ios, 'your version'
   ```

   If the deployment target is set to a lower version, try increasing it to meet the requirements of the dependency:

   ```rb
   platform :ios, '13.0'
   ```

   Then, save the file.
2. **Update Flutter and Plugins**:

   Make sure you are using the latest version of Flutter and your plugins. Run the following commands:

   ```
   flutter upgrade
   flutter pub upgrade
   ```
3. **Install Pods**:

   In the terminal, navigate to your project's `ios` directory and run:

   ```
   pod install
   ```

   This will update the CocoaPods dependencies.
4. **Verify Dependency Versions**:

   Open the `Podfile.lock` file in the `ios` directory and ensure that the version of `flutter_google_places_sdk_ios` listed matches the version specified in your `pubspec.yaml` file.
5. **Check for Plugin Updates**:

   Check if there's an updated version of the `flutter_google_places_sdk_ios` plugin available. Sometimes, newer versions may have resolved compatibility issues.
6. **Contact Plugin Maintainers**:

   If the issue persists, consider reaching out to the maintainers of the `flutter_google_places_sdk_ios` plugin for further assistance.

Remember to create a backup of your project before making any significant changes to the `Podfile` or dependencies. This way, you can easily revert back if any issues arise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy